# Path not found when using Move-Item

Tags: powershell, scripting, powershell-2.0

I want to do to the following things:

1. do the listing of all the items in the directory
2. move the files according to their names into different location

Example: In my document folder I have various files. According to the file names, I will move them to different directory. I use the following script. But it is not working.

```
$allfiles = Get-ChildItem $home\documents
$count = 0
foreach($file in $allfiles)
{
    if ($file.name -like "*Mama*") 
    {
        move-item $file.name -Destination $home\documents\mom
        $count++
    }
    elseif ($file.name -like "*Papa*")
    {
        move-item -destination $home\documents\Dad
        $count++
    }
    elseif ($file.name -like "*bro")
    {
        Move-Item -Destination $home\documents\Brother
        $count++
    }
}
write-host "$count files been moved"
```

What I am doing wrong here?

My Error output is

move-item : Cannot find path 'C:\users\administrator\documents\Lecture3.txt' because it does not exist.

At line:6 char:10

- { move-item $file.name -Destination $home\documents\Win213SGG\lectures
- ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

  - CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (C:\users\admini...ts\Lecture3.txt:String) [Move-Item], ItemNotFoundExceptio 
    n
  - FullyQualifiedErrorId : PathNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.MoveItemCommand

move-item : Cannot find path 'C:\users\administrator\documents\Lecture3_revised.txt' because it does not exist.
At line:6 char:10
+        { move-item $file.name -Destination $home\documents\Win213SGG\lectures
+          ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (C:\users\admini...re3_revised.txt:String) [Move-Item], ItemNotFoundExceptio 
   n
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PathNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.MoveItemCommand

cmdlet Move-Item at command pipeline position 1

Supply values for the following parameters:

Path[0]:

Comment: What's not working? What do you expect, and what are you getting? Just posting code and telling us "it's broken" isn't helpful, to you or to future readers who may be experiencing similar problems; we need good descriptions of the actual symptoms.

Comment: it's not working?  Hmm..  I wonder what could be wrong?  Maybe you can share an error message?  Or what happened vs. what you expected to happen?

Comment: "but it is not working." is not particularly useful. How is it not working? Is it not moving the files? Are there errors? Is it moving the files to the wrong place? Are wombats appearing at your desk and eating the files?

Comment: Heh...lot's of typing going on all at once apparently.

Comment: it is showing like this
cmdlet Move-Item at command pipeline position 1
Supply values for the following parameters:
Path[0]:

Comment: That's because you need to move the item and not the file property i.e. `$file.Name`. Use this `move-item $file. -Destination $home\documents\mom` instead of `move-item $file.name -Destination $home\documents\mom` at all places (wherever `move-item` is used).

Comment: Please copy and paste the full error into your question.

Comment: You need to use `Move-Item $file.FullName` instead of `$file.Name`.
`$file.FullName` is the full path to the file, which the `Move-Item` command needs.  Or you could go with Niels answer below and use the pipeline

Answer (score 1):

Or you could make it even neater by using the pipe functionality in powershell. Like this, you don't have to specify with '-path' which file to move, but you can pass it on directly from the result of Get-ChildItem:

```
Get-ChildItem $home\documents | Foreach-Object {
    $count = 0
    if ($_.Name -like "*Mama*") 
    {
        $_ | Move-Item -Destination $home\documents\mom
        $count++
    }
    elseif ($_.Name -like "*Papa*")
    {
        $_ | Move-Item -Destination $home\documents\Dad
        $count++
    }
    elseif ($_.Name -like "*bro")
    {
        $_ | Move-Item -Destination $home\documents\Brother
        $count++
    }
}

write-host "$count files been moved"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this -

```
$allfiles = Get-ChildItem $home\documents
$count = 0
foreach($file in $allfiles)
{
    if ($file.name -like "*Mama*") 
    {
        move-item -path $file -Destination $home\documents\mom
        $count++
    }
    elseif ($file.name -like "*Papa*")
    {
        move-item -path $file -destination $home\documents\Dad
        $count++
    }
    elseif ($file.name -like "*bro")
    {
        Move-Item -path $file -Destination $home\documents\Brother
        $count++
    }
}
write-host "$count files been moved"
```

You haven't specified the File Name at two occasions which is a mandatory parameter for `move-item`. And at one place you are trying to move the files using the `Name` parameter which is not an `item`(in literal sense). See if above works for you.